# To prove the limit exists $lim_{x,y \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{-(x^2+y^2)}-1}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I want to prove the limit exists without the use of polar coordinates. I was asked to it by delta-epsilon method. However since it has $e^{-x^2+y^2}$ I can't seem to do it since I only know to do it with polinomials in fractions.

Thank you all so much.

Comment: The delta-epsilon in 2D is a transformation to polar coordinates

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4481537/815585 for similar approach

Comment: @MiguelQ You might want to try splitting the limit into two, with one for each variable, and use L’Hôpital’s Rule for each.

Comment: @MathAndPhysics That is insufficient to show existence of a multivariable limit, I am fairly certain

Comment: @MathAndPhysics Doing that would not show that the limit exists.

Comment: Try the series for the e function and prove that $| fx,y)-1|<\epsilon$ for $x^2+y^2<\delta$